# 'geopandas' has no attribute 'plotting' --- Problem in importing geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

Okay, so I am currently working on a project using Jupyter Notebook and had to create colormaped representations of USA counties, thus I realised that I need to install geopandas to proceed further.
So, on the mac terminal I wrote

```
pip install geopandas
```

and it installed v 0.10.2 for me.

But now when I am doing the following:

```
import geopandas
```

in notebook, it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-2ba400db65f5> in <module>
     23 import xlrd
     24 import plotly.figure_factory as ff
---> 25 import geopandas.plotting

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa
----> 4 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame  # noqa
      5 from geopandas.array import points_from_xy  # noqa
      6 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in <module>
     62 
     63 
---> 64 class GeoDataFrame(GeoPandasBase, DataFrame):
     65     """
     66     A GeoDataFrame object is a pandas.DataFrame that has a column

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in GeoDataFrame()
   1851         return self.geometry.difference(other)
   1852 
-> 1853     plot = CachedAccessor("plot", geopandas.plotting.GeoplotAccessor)
   1854 
   1855     @doc(_explore)

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'plotting' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

The complete block of code which is getting executed is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
import opendatasets as od
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot
import seaborn as sns
import re
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from math import pi
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from tqdm import tqdm
import shapely
import shapefile
import xlrd
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import geopandas
```

Kindly explain how can I solve this error and proceed further. I have tried all from my side for couple of hours.
What exactly is this 'most likely due to a circular import'? How to resolve it?

Comment: What is the output of ```import geopandas``` alone? Also, are you working with Anaconda?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes The output of `import geopandas` alone is same as shown above. And, I'm using Jupyter Notebook (ran `juyter lab` on the terminal) from [jupyter.org](http://jupyter.org) for this, but I do have Anaconda installed in my system.

Comment: Do you have a folder or a file called `geopandas` in the same folder by any chance?

Comment: @martinfleis now that I have checked, I saw that there are the following **geopandas** folders in the `My_folder` that I am working: `My_folder > opt > anaconda3 > lib > python3.8 > site-packages > geopandas` and `geopandas-0.10.2.dist-info`.

Comment: I mean directly in you current directory from which you run this script.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2123#issuecomment-925600416) mentions conda for installing geopandas is preferable. Try running in a new cell in your notebook `%conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`. The use of the `%` is important here. `%pip install` and `%conda install` magic from inside the running notebook are the way to go now when you want to install to the environment that the notebook is using, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). They can be helpful to try in cases like this.

Comment: @martinfleis Current directory has no folder called `geopandas`

Comment: @Wayne Thank you so much...it worked. I ran `%conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` in the notebook and then restarted it, and the map apperared. I will keep this in mind from now on.